# Integrating with variable limits with any functions being the input

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate integrals of different functions. I hope the code works such that for any given function I input, it evaluates the integral. The integral is with respect to the variable tau and there is another parameter t in the integrand.

I have tried defining the integrand first, and then pass it to the integral function.

```
integrand = @(tau,t,f0) double(t./(1.+tau).*double(f0(tau))); %tau is the independent variable, t is a parameter, and f0 is the function to be integrated
f_int = @(tau,t) integrand(tau,t,sin) %substitute f0 with sin 
integrate = @(t) integral(@(tau) f_int(tau,t),xmin,xmax)  %this part does the integration depending on t 

integrate(1) %integrate with t=1
```

And it shows the following errors.

> Error using sin Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in IDE Trial>@(tau,t)integrand(tau,t,sin)
>
> Error in IDE Trial>@(tau)f_int(tau,t)
>
> Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
>                   fx = FUN(t);
>
> Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
>               [q,errbnd] =
>               iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);
>
> Error in integralCalc (line 75)
>           [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);
>
> Error in integral (line 88) Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
>
> Error in IDE Trial>@(t)integral(@(tau)f_int(tau,t),xmin,xmax)
>
> Error in IDE Trial (line 29) integrate(1)

I realized that I cannot just put `sin` in the function without passing any arguments, and there is probably a much better way of doing this. Is there anyway to fix the code such that it can do the job? Any help will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `sin` or any other function as a function handle using `@`:

```
integrand = @(tau,t,f0) double(t./(1.+tau).*double(f0(tau))); 
f_int = @(tau,t) integrand(tau,t,@sin) %substitute f0 with sin
```

Or create an anonymous function first, and then directly pass its handle:

```
fun = @(t) exp(t)*sin(t); % some combination of functions 

integrand = @(tau,t,f0) double(t./(1.+tau).*double(f0(tau))); 
f_int = @(tau,t) integrand(tau,t,fun) %substitute f0 with fun
```

Since `fun` is already a handle, you don't need to add the `@`.